# NodeJS requiring modules, module.exports.X vs module.exports={x}

Tags: node.js, require

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between exporting modules like:

```
module.exports.getUserIP = function getUserIP(req) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    return ip;
}
```

Or just declaring it:

```
function getUserIP(req) {
    // retrieve user IP from req object
    // Build this function to be more accurate/use more sources.
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    return ip;
}
```

and exporting at the bottom:

```
module.exports = { getUserIP }
```

or even:

```
module.exports = {getUserIP:getUserIP}
```

or

```
module.exports = {'getUserIP':getUserIP}
```

My problem is: when i call the function getUserIP from another file:

```
var mainbody = require('./app.js');//getUserIP is in here.
const gl = require('geoip-lite');
var ax = require('axios');

module.exports.getloc = function getloc(req, ip, property) {
    //return location from IP.
    if (req) {
        var ipGuest = mainbody.getUserIP(req); //HERE
    } else {
        var ipGuest = ip;
    }....
```

I get an error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxgpC.png)

However, when I use the FIRST method to export the function:

```
module.exports.getUserIP = function getUserIP(req) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    return ip;
}
```

Then it works perfectly.

What's the difference?

Comment: are you exporting multiple similar functions from app.js? if yes, using the 2nd method overwrites the entire exports object each time you do it

Comment: I am not. I only have one module.exports = {} at the bottom of each file.

Other functions work, BUT this one function doesn't get exported like the others for some reason. Only if I export that one specifically using the module.exports.name = function()..etc

It works, but it just looks messy to export 8 classes at the bottom, and 1 class inline with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use

`module.exports = { getUserIP: getUserIP }`

This way you can just look at the export statement at the end of your file and know which functions are being exported from a particular file

The `module.exports = {getUserIP};` is nothing but a shorthand of the above syntax(ES6 Magic). What it typically does is allows you to write this way `{ getUserIP }` if the key name to be same as function/variable name like `{ getUserIP: getUserIP }` where `getUserIP` can be a variable or a function or a ES6 class.

Answer (score 1):

All the examples you show will work properly, but they do have some different affects.

By default `module.exports` is already initialized to an empty object.  So, when you do something like this:

```
module.exports.getUserIP = function() {...}
```

You are assigning a new property to the existing object that module.exports already pointed to.  One advantage of this scheme is that you can easily add more properties the same way.

```
module.exports.getUserRegion = function() {}
```

This will add one more property to that same object without disturbing the first one you already added.

---

On the other hand, all of these are identical:

```
module.exports = {getUserIP: getUserIP}
module.exports = {'getUserIP':getUserIP}
module.exports = { getUserIP }   // ES6 shorthand for the previous syntax
```

and, they all end up with the same result as each other, but they all replace module.exports with a new object that has your one new property in it.

If you then tried to add another property:

```
module.exports = {getUserRegion};
```

That would again assign a whole new object to `module.exports` and you would have just wiped out the object that previously had `getUserIP` on it.   When assigning a new object, you would typically assign an object that had all your properties on it:

```
module.exports = {getUserIP: function() {...}, getUserRegion: function() {...}};
```

Thus, not wiping out something you had already put there.

---

All of your schemes should work fine as long as you aren't overwriting `module.exports` with a new object and thus overwriting the object that already had some of your methods on it.

Comment: I don't believe I am over-writting the module. I think there is some fundamental difference between: 

module.exports.functionX = functionX

And module.exports = {functionX,functionY,functionZ}

Comment: @ManojKumar - There is no fundamental difference in the end result other than replacing the original `module.exports` object with a new and different object.  If nobody ever used the original object, then it should not matter at all.  You can do it either way.  If you have one that works and the other doesn't, then there's something else going on that you aren't showing us that is causing a problem.  We'd need to see the ACTUAL code (in it's entirety) that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this exporting modules concept, just think module.export is a simple object. you can bind anything to that object as do with normal javascript objects. 
Finally when you require that module by `require('path to js')` you will get that exported object. If you export number of items in your module you can return them back by giving the names of the tag.